# Equalivent of VB6's vbUnicode in NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Is the NET equivalent for vbUnicode UTF32Encoding/UTF32Decoding?

Comment: It's hard to know if there's an equivalent, since you don't show us a code example of how you use it in VB6.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3sz0f8a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vbUnicode is just a constant. It's meaningless by itself. Show us some code. And what are you trying to do?

Are you converting an ANSI string to UTF32 with [StrConv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263373(v=vs.60).aspx) like this?

```
newString = StrConv(ansiString, vbUnicode)
```

A VB.Net equivalent might be [Encoding.Default.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) because [Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) is for the ANSI encoding

```
newString = Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ansiStringAsByteArray)
```

But it might depend on the code you used to obtain the ANSI string

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are looking for, but the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) classes, in particular [`Encoding.UTF32Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf32encoding.aspx) is probably what you need.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's all guesswork, but it's more likely that the OP needs [`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx). A common use of `vbUnicode` in VB6 is to convert Windows "ANSI" strings into UTF-16 to store them in a VB6 native string (which should be UTF-16). See my answer. It's unlikely UTF-32 would be used in conjunction with `vbUnicode` in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.Default` from @MarkJ's answer worked for me but I was a little nervous because it seems the default depends on your locale.  Found KB [311338](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311338) that shows how to explicitly specify the character set, and recommends 1252 for Western European characters.  So converting Mark's example, that becomes:

```
newString = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(ansiStringAsByteArray)
```

On my U.S English system, that gives the same results as `Encoding.Default`, but specifying 1252 should theoretically give the same results regardless of locale.

**Update 1/18/2016**

After seeing @MarkJ's comment below, I did a little more research and found that [VB6 StrConv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263373%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) does in fact use the default locale unless you specify one. (And you can only specify a LocaleID, e.g. 1033 for U.S. English, not the ANSI code page, e.g. 1252 for Western European.) So `Encoding.Default` is a closer equivalent to `StrConv` without a LocaleID. `GetEncoding(1252)` adds specificity that was not in Mark's VB6 example.

Comment: All true, I will just note that VB6 conversions will differ based on your locale so if you are looking for an exact equivalent of VB6 behaviour  - say if your users run your program in different locales - `Encoding.Default` is the best choice. In other situations you might want to specify the locale.